# Adaptive bitrate video host without ads

Tags: video, video-player

As my work uses Office 365, we have Microsoft Stream, which replaced Microsoft Stream Classic, which replaced Office 365 Video. Unfortunately, it doesn't appear able to set external viewer permission. Is there a similar alternative, without ads like YouTube has?

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/trying-to-put-large-video-files-on-my-website-and-having-difficulties/) suggests [Vimeo Pro](https://vimeo.com/professionals?vcid=37312) (€16/month billed annually) or [Bunny.net](https://bunny.net/stream/) ($0.01/GB), as adaptive bitrate streaming can't be done via a WordPress plugin.